# In a file upload Q in Qualtrics, how can I save File ID into embedded data?

Tags: file, url, upload, qualtrics

In a file upload question one of the pieces of data that is collected by Qualtrics is a File ID. File ID shows up in the final survey data, and it is also the last part of the File URL which is accessible using Piped Text. (it is usually something in this format: "F_RCeSTUWycCJPdrr" ).

Is it possible to write a code to save the File ID into an embedded data upon clicking on Next in that page?

I am completely new to and unfamiliar with Java and coding in general, so please respond as if you are explaining it to somebody that knows nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the file url in a subsequent question or in the survey flow with something like ${q://QID1/UploadedFileLink}. A JavaScript in a subsequent question to extract the FileID and save it in an embedded variable named FileID would be:

```
var fileURL = "${q://QID1/UploadedFileLink}";
var fileID = fileURL.substring(fileURL.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('FileID', fileID);
```

The embedded variable FileID must be defined in the survey flow before the question that contains the script.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly after a very a small change ( '/' instead of '=').